# Rで条件分岐でデータフレームを作成したらエラーがでる

Tags: r

```
kin<-c(-3,5,7,-6)
kin1<-kin[0<=kin] #0以上
kin2<-kin[0>kin]  #0未満

y<-c(1,2,3,4)

kihon<-data.frame(y) #データフレーム作成
```

プラスとマイナスを条件分岐で計算

```
for(i in 1:length(kin){
 if(kin1){
  pu<-data.frame(kin1*10) #プラスの計算
  colnames(pu)<-c("point") #ポイント名の変更
 }
 if(kin2){
  mi<-data.frame(kin2*30) #マイナスの計算
  colnames(pu)<-c("point") #ポイント名の変更
 }
}

pumi<-rbind(pu,mi) #プラスとマイナスのデータを連結
mydata<-data.frame(y,pumi) #データフレーム完成
```

このようにコードを書くと

> There were 50 or more warnings(use warning() to see the first 50)

上記のような赤メッセージが表示されます。

あと、mydataのデータフレームはpumiのマイナスとプラスを分けて別の方法で計算してから、もう一度同じ列に入れなおしているので、yのデータのような1,2,3,4の並びになりません。

データフレームと上の赤メッセージはどのように対処すればよいでしょうか。

Answer (score 1):

なさりたいのはこういう事でしょうか？

```
kin <- c(-3, 5, 7, -6)
y <- c(1, 2, 3, 4)

kihon <- data.frame(y, point = NA)  #データフレーム作成

# プラスとマイナスを条件分岐で計算
for(i in 1:length(kin)){
  if(kin[i] >= 0){
    kihon[i, "point"] <- kin[i] * 10  #ポイント名の変更
  }
  if(kin[i] < 0){
    kihon[i, "point"] <- kin[i] * 30  #ポイント名の変更
  }
}

kihon  #データフレーム完成
```

参考までに、以下のやり方のほうがシンプルでわかりやすいかと思います。

```
kin <- c(-3, 5, 7, -6)
kihon <- data.frame(kin, point = ifelse(kin >= 0, kin * 10, kin * 30))
kihon
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。おかげで解決しました。